# digital shower fed from shower pump -- low or high pressure?

Tags: bathroom, shower

We currently have a gravity-fed salamander shower pump (this one https://www.salamanderpumps.co.uk/product/ct-50-xtra-ct50-xtra/12) and would like to use it to feed a digital mixer shower (this one for example https://www.tritonshowers.co.uk/host-single-outlet-digital-mixer-with-control-black).

Triton's website says that the low-pressure model should be used for gravity-fed systems, but doesn't give any indication if this is the case for a *pumped* gravity-fed system (the low-pressure model has a max static pressure requirement of 1 bar, but the pump is a 1.5 bar pump). Furthermore, it says that the high-pressure model range is 1 bar to 5 bars, but should only be used with 1) combi boilers 2) unvented pressure cylinder or 3) mains pressurised thermal store system (none of these are our setup).

Which Triton model should we use if we are feeding it from our 1.5 bar pump: low-pressure or high-pressure?

Comment: Neither is suitable - why not remove the old shower pump and use the low pressure version? You don't save much money by trying to keep the old pump and there's a possibility you wouldn't get satisfactory results trying to use the high pressure version.

Answer (score 1):

If one unit has a max pressure of 1 bar and your system provides 1.5 bar, it seems logical that this would be too much pressure for a max 1 bar system.

I'd recommend the 1 to 5 bar system, as your 1.5 bar supply is in that range.

If you're still not sure, then contact the manufacturers and see what they say.